# Stop Mail from keeping sent drafts?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, imap

I use iCloud and I like Mail to save my drafts on the server.

But I have no desire to keep them as drafts after they are sent.  But Mail keeps the drafts and I have to manually delete them.

I don't to disable the saving of drafts on the server, this isn't a solution.

Comment: Are you referring to the drafts that end up stored when the network drops a connection from time to time (and the system errs on the side of not deleting a draft you may need)? Those do accumulate over time but shouldn't be one for each and every sent message (you can count both boxes or measure the next 10 messages you send to test this out)

Comment: Hmm, I have been working on an unreliable connection lately.  I will experiment more, thank you bmimke.